# NSPopupButton that displays image not text of selected item

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton

I am creating a NSPopUpButton that has multiple NSMenuItems each with an image and a title. The functionality I am trying to create is as such: When the popup is displaying I would like it to behave normally, displaying the title and image, however when the popup is closed I would like the button to show only the image of the selected item. Much like how the Calendars Mac app behaves.

[image: When Closed]

[image: When Open]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like?

Comment: `NSPopUpButton` is a subclass of `NSButton`. Did you try to set the title and image when an item is selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is to set `popupButton.imagePosition = .imageOnly`. Here's an example:

```
func swatch(size: NSSize, color: NSColor) -> NSImage {
    let image = NSImage(size: size)
    image.lockFocus()
    color.drawSwatch(in: NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    image.unlockFocus()

    return image
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let homeItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Home", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
    let workItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Work", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
    let familityItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Family", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")

    let size = NSSize(width: 12, height: 12)
    homeItem.image = swatch(size: size, color: .blue)
    workItem.image = swatch(size: size, color: .purple)
    familityItem.image = swatch(size: size, color: .orange)

    let menu = NSMenu()
    menu.addItem(homeItem)
    menu.addItem(workItem)
    menu.addItem(familityItem)
    popupButton.menu = menu
    popupButton.imagePosition = .imageOnly
}
```

Comment: You can set the image position in the storyboard or xib.

Comment: Worked perfect, I knew I was missing something easy. Thanks!